# p5js 'line is not a function'

Tags: javascript, loops, processing, p5.js

I am trying to use p5js to take a group of points and loop through them in order to draw lines. My problem is that for some reason, I keep getting the error message that 'line is not a function.' Why?

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(255)

}

function draw() {
    strokeWeight(50);
    drawLetter(letterA);
}

const letterA = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 10, y1: 20, x2: 40, y2: 50 },
        { x1: 90, y1: 60, x2: 60, y2: 100 },
        { x1: 200, y1: 20, x2: 30, y2: 45 }
    ]
}

function drawLetter(letter) {

    for (let i = 0; i < letter.lines.length; i++) {
        const line = letter.lines[i];
        const { x1, y1, x2, y2 } = line;

        line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` is not a function, because you've named a local variable "`line`". Th local variable covers the function "`line`". Rename the variable (e.g. `coordinates`):

```js
function drawLetter(letter) {

    for (let i = 0; i < letter.lines.length; i++) {
        const coordinates = letter.lines[i];
        const { x1, y1, x2, y2 } = coordinates;

        line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }
}
```

Or skip the local variable completely:

```js
function drawLetter(letter) {

    for (let i = 0; i < letter.lines.length; i++) {
        const { x1, y1, x2, y2 } = letter.lines[i];

        line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    }
}
```